# Binding with Static properties in ListView ItemTemplate

Tags: wpf, binding, itemtemplate

I'm having some problems with WPF binding.

I have an assembly with some const properties in class Values, that correspond to columns from datatable.
I want to bind the value from a column to a TextBlock using the const property to specify the column at a ListView  ItemTemplate like shown in the code:

```
 xmlns:C="clr-namespace:WPFApplication1.Entities;assembly=WPFApplication1">
  <Grid>  
   <ListView>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding {x:Static C:Values.FieldCode}}" /> /*<- Don't work*/
            /*Works like this: <TextBlock Text="{Binding [CODE]}" />*/ 
          </DataTemplate>
       </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
  </Grid>
```

If I use binding with the static property I I'm not able to show the value in the datarow but if I use the Binding like this [CODE] I'm able to show the value.

What is appening?
Any clue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use your static property as the Source, not the Path, which is the default attribute for Binding:

```
{Binding Source={x:Static C:Values.FieldCode}}
```

Answer (score 1):

the italic text is not correct, please read from **EDIT1**:
*It is not possible to bind to static properties. Binding always needs an instance of the Class. It is possible by instantiating the class as resource of in the code behind and set that class as the datacontext*

**EDIT1:**

Add a static property of type

```
public static string FieldCode = "Code";
public static PropertyPath FieldCodePath = new PropertyPath(FieldCode);
```

Change the Binding to the binding below:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path={x:Static C:Values.FieldCodePath}, IsAsync=true}" />
```

I hope this helps

Comment: The Listview datacontext  is a Datatable, the static filed is only the column name that I have specified in a Class.
My point is not to use the column name itself but a const property from a class that is the column name.
I'm able to do <TextBlock Text="{Binding {x:Static C:Values.FieldCode}}" /> outside the ItemTemplate. so I think the problem is the binding and the acess to the static field inside the ItemTemplate. Any Ideas?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly if I think that you would like to set the path of the binding to the static property that references the columnname instead of putting the columnname in code as a string?

Comment: Is EDIT1 of my answer helping you with it or do you need something else.